# Valide the amount of records allowed from the user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to create a validation that makes sure the user can never have more than X records that have status == live. However they can have several records, but not more than X can be live.

I'm thinking the validation needs to be checked on every save. Because people can try to change the status, thus have more than X records live, so I don't want them to change the action if X are already live.

Here's what I got so far:

Campaign.rb

```
belongs_to :user
validate :amount_allowed
private 

def amount_allowed
  if user.campaigns.where(live: true).count > user.live_keywords_allowed
    errors.add(:base, "Exceeds your account limit")
  end
end
```

and in my user model:

```
has_many :campaigns
# amount of live keywords allowed depending on payment plan
def live_keywords_allowed 
  if self.plan_id == 1
    5
  elsif self.plan_id == 2
    7
  elsif self.plan_id == 3
    10
  else
    7
  end 
end
```

however this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `validate :amount_allowed, :on => :create`

Comment: that doesn't work, as said in the text. The bottom is in my user model, the top is in my campaigns model

Comment: it's not in the user model, it's in the campaigns model

Comment: Can you add this info to your question please, and also your schema associations for Campaign & User?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are testing the number that are already in the database, and whether that is **over** the limit.  Let's say the limit is 5, and you have 5 already, and you're trying to add another one: this wouldn't fail your valid test.

You need to be testing whether the number already in the database **plus the one you're trying to create** would take it over the limit.

This should work:

```
def amount_allowed
  if self.live? && self.user_other_live_campaigns_count >= user.live_keywords_allowed
    errors.add(:base, "Exceeds your account limit")
  end
end

def user_other_live_campaigns_count
  if self.new_record?
    conditions = ["live = ?", true]
  else
    conditions = ["live = ? and id <> ?", true, self.id]
  end
  user.campaigns.where(conditions).count
end
```

The logic for the test is saying "if this campaign is live, and there are `user.live_keywords_allowed` or more live campaigns for this user already, **not counting this one**, then it's not valid.

EDIT: bugfix.  i forgot this quirk of sql

```
"where id <> NULL"
```

you'd expect this to return all records where the id isn't null, but it doesn't return anything.  So, we need a different test for new records (with no id) and existing records (which do have an id).

EDIT2: there was a lot of repetition in my previous edit, so i've DRYed it up a bit by splitting it into two methods.

Comment: For some reason I can still keep on adding campaigns over the limit.

Comment: I changed validate :amount_allowed, :on => [:create, :update] and now it works on update it seems, however still not on new / create

Comment: No worries.  I've got a feeling my logic could be expressed more simply but the main thing is that it works :)